# getting facebook most shared stuff

Tags: php, facebook, api, rss

I was looking at websites like http://itstrending.com/, facediggs.com/ and I'm questioning myself how do they extract the most shared topics from facebook? I would like to build a similar widget for my blog. I searched the API but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, but here are more sites that might provide additional insight into what you're looking for: http://mashable.com/2010/08/18/facebook-search-services/

Answer (score 0):

I found this page which is worth looking at

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/323

Half way down this page is a url you can use to check pages on your site, it returns xml with some good stats. Hope this helps.

**Running an FQL (Facebook Query Language) query on the link_stat table.**
Below: example url to put in your browser and press enter.
It returns xml with true and a count which you can use however you like. This returned 957 last time I tried it. Be carefull using quotes around the url you want to query.

[How many facebook shares (total) does stackoverflow have?](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27stackoverflow.com%27)

[Another example with 2 urls](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20IN%28%27stackoverflow.com%27,%27www.facebook.com%27%29)